# C# program that uses events

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

I am trying to learn C#. Please tell me if the following code respects coding standards and naming conventions because I want to write beautiful code. The purpose of this program was to help me understand different concepts that I've learned in the last few days but I was having difficulties thoroughly understanding them (especially events and delegates). Please show me what you would change by exemplifying, not just by recommending, because I have a harder time understanding phrases than code.

For example, I've been told to use "async/await and the TPL". I've made a couple simple programs with them, yet I still don’t know how I would apply the concepts here. I'll keep trying while waiting for an answer from you, I'll be reading the chapters [from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the next few hours.

Also, I've been told I should have used `Action`. I want to use `Action`s because I like `Action` and `Func`, yet I don’t know where should I use `Action`.

**TProgram.cs:**

```
#define DEBUG
#define TRACE
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace LearnEventsAndOthers
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void OnTicked(object sender, TickingEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Event triggered in object {0} at tick {1}", ((Metronom)sender).Id, e.TickCount);
        }

        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            #region Standard Code - Init

            Console.InputEncoding = Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            Console.SetWindowSize(160, 56);
            Console.BufferHeight = 9000;
            Console.BufferWidth = 300;
#if DEBUG
            Console.WriteLine("The program is running in #DEBUG mode.");
#endif
#if TRACE
            Console.WriteLine("The program is running in #TRACE mode.");
#endif

            #endregion

            // Creating objects and testing overridden functions Equals and GetHashCode...
            Metronom m = new Metronom();
            Metronom n = new Metronom();
            Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(System.IO.File.CreateText("TraceInfo.txt")));
            Trace.AutoFlush = true;
            Debug.Indent();
            Debug.WriteLineIf(!m.Equals(n), string.Format("Objects n and m have been created and they have different IDs: {0} vs {1}", m.GetHashCode(), n.GetHashCode()));
            Debug.Assert(!m.Equals(n), "Objects n and m have been created but they are equal! This shouldn't happen.");

            // Testing event subscription...
            m.TickedEvent += OnTicked;
            n.TickedEvent += OnTicked;

            // Testing destructors...
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Press any key to destroy the objects!" + Environment.NewLine);
            Console.ReadKey();

            m.RequestStop();
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "The first object was destroyed. Waiting 5 seconds before destroying the second...");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            n.RequestStop();

            #region Standard Code - Exit

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress <enter> to exit!");
            Console.ReadLine();
            return 0;

            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

**Metronom.cs:**

```
#define DEBUG
#define TRACE
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace LearnEventsAndOthers
{
    public class TickingEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public long TickCount { get; set; }
    }

    public class Metronom
    {
        public event EventHandler<TickingEventArgs> TickedEvent;

        public Guid Id { get; private set; }

        public int RandomStop { get; private set; } // Used to trigger the TickedEvent at random time spans.

        protected internal const int SpeedModifier = 17777777;  // Used to control the speed at which events are triggered. Higher means slower.
        // Why did I make it protected internal? I really wanted to use the access modifier "internal".

        private readonly Thread _t;

        private volatile bool _shouldStop;

        public Metronom()
        {
            this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            checked
            {
                int hashCode = Math.Abs(this.GetHashCode());
                while (hashCode > SpeedModifier)
                    hashCode -= SpeedModifier;
                RandomStop = hashCode;
            }
            _t = new Thread(Clock) { IsBackground = true };
            _t.Start();
            Debug.WriteLine("Object initialized with GUID HashCode " + this.GetHashCode());

        }

        ~Metronom()
        {
            _t.Join();
            Debug.WriteLineIf(_t.IsAlive == false, string.Format("Thread from object {0} has been stopped.", this.Id));
            Debug.Assert(_t.IsAlive == false, string.Format("Thread from object {0} is still running.", this.Id));
        }

        protected virtual void OnTickedEvent(long l)
        {
            EventHandler<TickingEventArgs> handler = TickedEvent;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new TickingEventArgs() { TickCount = l });
        }

        public void RequestStop()
        {
            _shouldStop = true;
        }

        private void Clock()
        {
            Stopwatch c = new Stopwatch();
            c.Start();
            Debug.WriteLineIf(_t.IsAlive, string.Format("Thread from object {0} has gone LIVE!", this.Id));
            while (!_shouldStop)
            {
                long l = c.ElapsedTicks;
                if ((l % this.RandomStop) == 0)
                {
                    OnTickedEvent(l);
                }
            }
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return obj is Metronom && (((Metronom)obj).Id.Equals(Id));
        }

        public override sealed int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Id.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you learning about these features (TPL, finalizers, etc.) because you have some project in mind which requires them? Or just to know them? Because while they are very useful/important in certain situations, I wouldn't recommend them to a beginner. Instead of trying to learn all the language features, I'd start with the basic features and concentrate on design principles (SOLID, DRY, etc.). Then features can come as you need them. Just a suggestion, though.

Comment: But how would I know if I need them if they were unknown to me... Tomorrow I'll also search on google for SOLID, DRY and finalizers, look at what you did! :P

Comment: Please revise the title to state the purpose of the code *only*.  Any *requests* should just be in the post body.

Comment: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)

Comment: A note about event naming: you don't need the "-Event" suffix. Name it "Ticking" when it's raised before the tick, name it "Tick" when it is the actual event, and name it "Ticked" when it just happened -- see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/724375/225292)

Answer (score 6):

- `c`
- `l`
- `m`
- `n`
- `_t`

These are poorly named variables that don't follow what most developers have accepted as the norm.

You need to be more descriptive with your names, even when writing Generic code.

- `c` -> `clock` or `timer` or `stopwatch1`

That brings me to `l`....  You don't need it and shouldn't use it, it's a Magical Variable that is just smelly.

You should instead write it like this

```
private void Clock()
{
    Stopwatch clock = new Stopwatch();
    clock.Start();
    Debug.WriteLineIf(_t.IsAlive, string.Format("Thread from object {0} has gone LIVE!", this.Id));
    while (!_shouldStop)
    {
        if ((clock.ElapsedTicks % this.RandomStop) == 0)
        {
            OnTickedEvent(clock.ElapsedTicks);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

I see your point that you need that magic smelly variable to hold the exact value, but what if the timing is just right so that

```
l % this.RandomStop != 0
```

Just a thought.

---

**Edit:**

Now there is also an issue with your boolean `_shouldStop` and that you don't initialize it to a value, it may not cause a direct issue because if a boolean is not initialized it should return a false value when referenced (*IIRC*), but this is not a good habit to get into, if it were another object type it would return an error the first time that `Clock` is called.

Easy solution, since you don't want it stopped from the get go just set the variable on declaration

```
private volatile bool _shouldStop = false;
```

---

`m` and `n` are Metronomes, so their names should reflect that, each one is a Metronom.

Since this is a simple method for testing the class that you made I would just name them `metronome1` and `metronome2`.

If they served a specific purpose you could name them something more descriptive.

---

And that brings me to the last one

```
_t
```

Okay, it's a thread.

- Is it my thread?
- Is it your thread?
- Is it the main thread?
- Is it scope specific?
- Is this thread safe?
- What is the purpose of this thread?

You should be much more descriptive with your naming.

As a Developer you write code, it should read like a book, so write it elegantly and don't be skimpy.

When I read code and see a single letter variable I have to stop looking at the code and figure out what that letter represents because the name doesn't tell me anything about the object.

---

**Additional:**

I noticed that you declare your `Main` method as an integer method... not sure why you do that just to `return 0;`

You should just declare it `void` there isn't any reason that I can see that you  need an integer method.

Comment: Thank you Sir! I have updated the code and my mentality based on your recommendations. One thing I disagree with though...  
long elapsedTicks = stopwatch.ElapsedTicks;
This line is necessary because ElapsedTicks keeps getting incremented and I need the same value for the next few lines.

Comment: it shouldn't change that much between those 2 lines of code.

Answer (score 5):

There's a subtle bug hidden in your code.

> ```
> int hashCode = Math.Abs(this.GetHashCode());
> ```

When `Math.Abs` is passed `int.MinValue`, it throws an `OverflowException`:

> Negating the minimum value of a twos complement number is invalid.

`GetHashCode` defers to `Guid`'s `GetHashCode`, which makes no guarantees that it *won't* return `int.MinValue`.

How unlikely is it? Well I've had a program running for fifteen minutes now to find a `Guid` with a hash code of `int.MinValue` and I've only found one, but it can happen and it's good to be aware of (and fix!).

One neat way to fix the bug would be

```
int hashCode = this.GetHashCode() & int.MaxValue;
```

that is, assuming you don't really care about the value returned by `GetHashCode`, you just want some non-negative integer.

---

This loop

> ```
> while (!_shouldStop)
> {
>     long l = c.ElapsedTicks;
>     if ((l % this.RandomStop) == 0)
>     {
>         OnTickedEvent(l);
>     }
> }
> ```

pegs the CPU. Two metronomes increases my CPU usage from ~10% to 50%; four metronomes takes it up to 100%. Take a look at [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) for a way of getting the same sort of functionality without using up all the CPU.

---

I would strongly recommend against using `#define DEBUG` and `#define TRACE` in your files like this. To compile without them would require going through every file in your project and removing those lines.

These symbols can be set in Visual Studio at a project level in the project build settings:

[image: Visual Studio Project Build settings]

Alternatively you can set them using the [`/define`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z.aspx) option if you're compiling by hand.